Can't get selenium to work in my python lambda
Using selenium 4.19 on python 12 runtime enviornment.
here's a code snipped from the function that's using selenium:
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")  # Disable GPU hardware acceleration
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Disable sandbox mode
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # Disable shared memory usage
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")  # Disable extensions

    # Create a webdriver instance with headless option
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)  # Navigate to the webpage
    driver.get(KWENTA_LIQUIDATION_PRICE_URL)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Wait up to 10 seconds
    tokens = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "chakra-text.css-2utkvs")))

Here's the error message:
[WARNING]    2024-04-08T19:43:02.401Z    da9c31d6-1553-417f-8b45-8589a0b2adad    Cache folder (/home/sbx_user1051/.cache/selenium) cannot be created: Read-only file system (os error 30)
Tried using the headless browser and other headers I found online but none seem to work.

From the path in the error message, the issue seems to be with Selenium Manager. It downloads the requested driver and stores it (and other files) in that .cache path. If you can't change the permissions on that path, you can always choose a different cache path by setting cache-path,



CLI argument
Configuration file
Env variable
Description




--cache-path <CACHE_PATH>
cache-path="CACHE_PATH"
SE_CACHE_PATH=CACHE_PATH
Local folder used to store downloaded assets (drivers and browsers), local metadata, and configuration file. See next section for details. Default: ~/.cache/selenium. For Windows paths in the TOML configuration file, double backslashes are required (e.g., C:\custom\cache).



See the docs linked above for more info.

As mentioned in the other answer, issue seems to be with the OS level permissions of the folder, where SeleniumManager will download chromedriver.exe.
In case you are not able to resolve the issue with SeleniumManager, you can always download relevant chromedriver.exe manually from internet and set the path manually in your code. See below to know more about it.

Download latest stable chrome driver from below link
Link to download latest stable chrome driver

Refer code below to set the chrome driver path manually in your code.


from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service("C:/<full path of chromedriver.exe where you downloaded it>/chromedriver.exe")

# Create a webdriver instance with headless option
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=service)  # Navigate to the webpage
driver.get(KWENTA_LIQUIDATION_PRICE_URL)

